# GLSL interlacing seems to skip even rows on 3DTV

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, interlacing

I'm trying to create some interlaced images to output on a 3DTV. My method uses OpenGL's stencil buffer to draw a grid of lines on each even row of pixels. On my laptop, the resulting image **looks** interlaced, but when I output to the 3DTV (via HDMI cable), it looks as though the lines are not drawn on each even row of pixels. The vertical resolution of my laptop and the TV is 1080 pixels. The screen coordinates used below range from (-1, -1) for bottom left of the screen to (1, 1) for top right. Here is the code I am using to draw the grid on the stencil buffer. I'd be grateful if someone could sanity check it for me, to see if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. If my code is fine, the problem might be the TV resizing the output from the laptop.

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glStencilOp (GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE); 
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS,1,1); 
const int stencilsize = 2500;
// hardcoding 2500, not the greatest solution in the world i know...
GLfloat stencilVertices[stencilsize] = {0.0};
//if we know the window height, we can draw a line in the stencil buffer on even row of pixels in the window
currheight = 1080; 
GLint i = 0;
GLfloat ht = -1;
/*start ht @ -1, increase by 4/currheight each time, until 1 is reached*/
while ((ht < 1) && (i < stencilsize-4)) 
{
    stencilVertices[i] = -1;    //left edge of screen
    i++;
    stencilVertices[i] = ht;    //current line's y coord
    i++;
    stencilVertices[i] = 1;     //right edge of screen
    i++;
    stencilVertices[i] = ht;    //current line's y coord
    i++;
    ht += 4.0/currheight;   //increase ht by (4/(height of window)) each time to mark even rows only (until ht == 1)
}
glGenBuffers(1, &m_ui32Stencilpattern); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ui32Stencilpattern);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (stencilsize * sizeof(GLfloat)), stencilVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, stencilsize);
```

Comment: @EmileCormier I don't know what this has to do with gamedev, though, which is not a dumpster for anything graphics-related.

Comment: @ChristianRau : I figured there'd be more OpenGL experts over there.

Comment: @Bart: Oops, I assumed he wanted a code-review based only on his title. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stencil buffer is not quite the right tool for this. Line interlacing is more easily done using a fragment shader these days. And in the days before OpenGL-3 I'd do this using a polygon stipple (like I did in my interlaced 3D TV patch I got included into mplayer). This saves you the struggle with getting your geometry at the right position.

In the shader you can select between the two source images on a per pixel basis, using the gl_FragCoord viewport pixel coordinate as conditional. Or you draw two passes and `discard` fragments of either line/column.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf. So do you think fragment shader code like:
    `if(((myTexCoord/2.0 - vec2(ivec2(myTexCoord.y/2.0)))).y < 0.5)
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(leftEyeTexture, myTexCoord);
    else
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(rightEyeTexture, myTexCoord);`   Should work? It only outputs the left eye texture at the moment. I think the even/odd check needs fixing. Don't have access to '%' or '&' operators unfortunately.

Comment: @Stereoscopic: Uh, no. I was thinking along the line `if(gl_FragCoord.y % 2 == 0) { gl_FragColor = texture2D(left, …); } else { texture2D(right, …); }`. Remember that you're interested in screen/viewport space interlacing, which means you're want to base this of the fragment pixel coordinate.

Comment: I see! As per your suggestion I changed my if line to `if(((gl_FragCoord/2.0 - vec4(ivec4(gl_FragCoord.y/2.0)))).y < 0.5)`, it seems to work! I'm still indexing my images with the varying `myTexCoord`, but that's ok, right? I don't have a 3DTV nearby at the moment, so I can't check, but the output looks similar to what I was getting with the stencil buffer method. What's the difference? If I connect to a 3DTV via HDMI, this **should** output the left image on all even rows and the right image on all odd, but shouldn't the stencil buffer method also have done this? In any case, thank you! :)

Comment: @Stereoscopic: The stencil buffer method will be subject to antialiasing, which pretty much thwarfs any attempts to interlace the picutures.

Comment: Antialiasing, the villain! I assume it takes the form of rounding down my 4/1080 coordinate jumps , which means the grid of interlaced stencil buffer lines are not truly being drawn on one row of pixels each? I had begun to think the TV was at fault, resizing the HDMI input in some way. Wish I had a 3DTV around so I could test this new method!

Comment: I don't mean to bother you, but could you please explain where the lines drawn on the stencil buffer are antialiased? It does seem to be the case, but I am unsure why.

Comment: @Stereoscopic: The stencil buffer works very much like the depth buffer (in fact the same functional unit of the GPU is used for this). Just like the depth buffer the stencil buffer operates on multisample fragments if antialiasing is used. If you don't get your stenciling geometry perfectly matched up with the multisample pixel coverage you get this effect.